# "return render" vs "render ... and return" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

Is there any functional difference in writing `return render 'edit'` and `render 'edit' and return`? Are both syntaxes safe to use?

The `return render` syntax is slightly more concise, but the `render and return` is advocated officially here [Avoiding Double Render Errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors).

`return render` would return whatever value the render method return and `render and return` would return a `nil` from the controller method.

Comment: Another tricky thing is to use `render and return`, don't do `render && return`, although your Rubocop may not favour it.

Comment: Rubocop does indeed flag it and suggests using `&&`. Rubocop isn't always right.

Comment: I personally think `return render` is much clearer, especially if the call is long, and the `and` far right.  Visually, `return render` is crystal clear.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629976/ruby-return-vs-and-return) for why you should be careful about using `render "foo" && return`. Note also that you can get around the linting issue by adding parentheses with your render method like so: `render("foo") && return`

Answer (score 23):

You answered your question at the end:

> return render would return whatever value the render method return and
>   render and return would return a nil from the controller method

The important thing is that you *are* returning - this prevents any other code in the controller action from running - hence protecting you from double render errors. I don't believe anything is actually listening for the return value of the controller actions.

If I had to guess why the preferred method is `and return` I would say that it reads like prose, which is the ruby way. That is to say, it sounds like a sentence "Render categories and return" rather than "return render categories"

Answer (score 2):

All methods in Ruby return a result related on the last method's line.
If you want to return a result without waiting whole method, you can return value with keyword `return`

Example:

```
def hello1
  'I m first' # executes but is never returned
  'I m second' # result
end

def hello2
  return 'I m first' # result
  'I m second' # this line will be never executeed
end

puts hello1
# => 'I m second'
puts hello2
# => 'I'm first'
```

And the method `render` acts the same way

But `render` method is written like a procedure (it has result, but the result is a `true`), thus you can just `return` after `render` call