# Ruby: "&& return" vs "and return"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While going through the Rails guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors ,
I wrote a test program to test Ruby's `&& return`, and I got this strange behavior:

```
def test1
  puts 'hello' && return
  puts 'world'
end

def test2
  puts 'hello' and return
  puts 'world'
end
```

This is the result output:

```
irb(main):028:0> test1
=> nil
irb(main):029:0> test2
hello
world
=> nil
```

What accounts for the difference?

Comment: Good discussion about this here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217700

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Check out [the difference between `and` and `&&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426826/difference-between-and-and-in-ruby). In the examples you give the method `puts` is called without parens around it's arguments and the difference in precedence changes how it is parsed.

In test 1 `&&` has higher precedence than the method call. So what's actually happening is `puts('hello' && return)`. Arguments are always evaluated before the methods they're called with -- so we first evaluate `'hello' && return`. Since `'hello'` is truthy the boolean does not short circuit and `return` is evaluated. When return we exit the method without doing anything else: so nothing is ever logged and the second line isn't run.

In test 2 `and` has a lower precedence than the method call. So what happens is `puts('hello') and return`. The `puts` method logs what is passed to it and then returns `nil`. `nil` is a falsey value so the `and` expression short circuits and the `return` expression is never evaluated. We just move to the second line where `puts 'world'` is run.

Comment: thank you!! i notice what the problem is ~~ but  i cann't see where "&& has higher precedence than the method call." exist in the http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4, i cann't prove it...

Comment: So well explained...I feel that my upvote and saying thanks is not enough for this knowledge-masterpiece you've shared with us. 