# Rails returning 204 when explicitly told to return 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Having a weird issue with rails (5.0.5) right now.  I know the render and return is running because I can use binding.pry to step in.  It should be returning with a status code forbidden however when I run my test it returns with status code 204 no content instead.

```
# we already know this user has permission for org_claim_codes#create but we need to check they are part of this org
unless @current_user.orgs.map(&:id).include?(new_org_claim_code_params[:org_id].to_i) || @current_user.has_permission?('*', '*')
  render json: { errors: ['user not authorized']}, status: :forbidden && return
end
```

In my test I expect the status to be forbidden

```
expect(response).to have_http_status(:forbidden)
```

but i get an error stating

```
Failures:

1) OrgClaimCodesController#create permissions does not allow a user without permission weather or not they are in the org
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:forbidden)
   expected the response to have status code :forbidden (403) but it was :no_content (204)
 # ./spec/controllers/org_claim_codes_controller_spec.rb:49:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.3044 seconds (files took 2.26 seconds to load)
```

1 example, 1 failure

Full controller code

```
# create new claim code based on org_id
def create
# we already know this user has permission for org_claim_codes#create but we need to check they are part of this org
unless @current_user.orgs.map(&:id).include?(new_org_claim_code_params[:org_id].to_i) || @current_user.has_permission?('*', '*')
  render json: { errors: ['user not authorized']}, status: :forbidden && return
end

claim = OrgClaimCode.new(new_org_claim_code_params)
if claim.save
  render json: claim
else
  render json: { errors: claim.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

end

full test

```
it 'does not allow a user without permission weather or not they are in the org' do
    current_user
    expect do
      post :create, params: { org_claim_codes: { org_id: create(:org).id } } # a different org than we set perms for
    end.to change(OrgClaimCode, :count).by(0)

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:forbidden)
  end
```

Comment: Just an FYI, forbidden error code is 403 not 401 :)

Answer (score 0):

In controller rewrite:

```
render json: { errors: ['user not authorized']}, status: :forbidden && return
```

**TO**

```
render json: { errors: ['user not authorized']}, status: :forbidden and return
```

**Explanation**:

> `&&` has higher [precedence](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4) than `and`. Besides, in your code `render json: { errors: ['user not authorized']}, status: :forbidden` is `true`, so it just executes this and do not goes for `return`.

[Check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629976/about-ruby-return-vs-and-return), it explains everything.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `&& return` or `and return` completely and it should work.
Also 403 is the error code for forbidden.